# Display Spotify songs in React without authentication

Tags: reactjs, audio, spotify, web-audio-api

I want to create an audio player in React with music from Spotify. My goal is to allow the user to listen to a preview of some music I've chosen beforehand.

I apologize if I haven't gone far enough in my research, but the resources I've consulted show that the user has to log in with his account. So I'd like to know if it's possible to publish a music sample in a personal, non-commercial application and have the user listen to it without having to log in.

I don't know if this is important, but I have a Spotify Premium account.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995704/getting-and-playing-30-second-previews-from-spotify